# Concerning HC-SR04's capability in measuring distance

Tags: arduino

I am currently working with the HC-SR04 ultrasonic sensor to measure the distance from the sensor to the surface.

Problem is that the resulting value from the sensor is neither consistent nor accurate within reason.

I read that the HC-SR04 has a maximum reading range of up to 400cm.

My current situation is that the sensor can reasonably measure up to 20 cm, but when it exceeds that it rapidly fails.

For example, the distance between the sensor and surface is approximately 170cm, but the sensor says it is approximately 50cm.

Here is how pins are connected.
HC-SR04------Arduino.
Trig    to  13.
Echo to  12
Vcc     to  5V
GND to  GND

Here is my code for Arduino.

```
#define echoPin1 12
#define trigPin1 13

float duration;
float distance1_1;

void setup()
{
    pinMode (echoPin1, INPUT);
    pinMode (trigPin1, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(trigPin1, LOW);

    Serial.begin (9600);
    Serial.println("Program Begins");
}

void loop()
{
    DIST();
    delay (1000);
}

void DIST()
{
    digitalWrite(trigPin1, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(2);
    digitalWrite(trigPin1, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(10);
    digitalWrite(trigPin1, LOW);
    duration=pulseIn(echoPin1, HIGH);
    distance1_1=(duration*0.0343)/2;
    Serial.println("Distance")
    Serial.println(distance1_1);
}
```

Comment: better ask on the arduino stackexchange website. you will get better response over there

Answer (score 0):

1. Try using different Arduino pins for connecting the echo and trigger pins. The pin 13 of Arduino is connected to the LED and there are some reports of problems while using pin13 for the ultrasonic sensor on certain Arduino models/revisions. So first try changing the pins.
2. Next, try a spare sensor (if available) and see if the results are consistent. Sometimes the problem is with the broken ultrasonic sensor.
3. Also, we need to know the exact hardware setput i.e. how are you mounting the sensor. There could be stray reflections from the nearby objects so need to be careful while mounting the sensor.
4. Finally, the return type of pulseIn is unsigned long. So you should
   store the value from pulseIn in a long datatype, not float.